# GoogleDrive SDK- searching files inside a folder

Tags: c#, url, request, google-drive-api

I am trying to get all the items underneath a specific folder.

I was using this documentation:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

And based on it I wrote the following:

```
string url = string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?'q'=\"'{0}' in parents\"", folderId);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

And I get an error:

> (401) UnAuthorized

Or when I copy-paste the request to the browser I get this:

> {  "error": {   "errors": [    {
>       "domain": "global",
>       "reason": "required",
>       "message": "Login Required",
>       "locationType": "header",
>       "location": "Authorization"    }   ],   "code": 401,   "message": "Login Required"  } }

I also used this question as a reference:
[Getting a list of files by folder on Drive SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400669/getting-a-list-of-files-by-folder-on-drive-sdk)
And I can't see what I've done differently

**EDIT:**
I have this parameter that contains the authentication:

```
DriveService service
```

Before, in order to get ALL files I was doing this:

```
FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();
```

But now when I'm trying to take specific items, I'm not sure how to combine that `service`

Comment: By specific items that's a query or something like that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start looking at the [C# quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs).

The quick start let you authorize from the console and then show you how to insert a file on Google Drive.

After you import the [.Net Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API) into the project you can write a code like this to get the files:

```
Private Sub GetFileList(ParentFolder As String)

    Authorize() 'Take care of authorization... you could use JS to ask the user and get the Auth Token

    'MSO - 20130423 - Search the Google Drive File with the specified foldername
    'Create the search request
    Dim oListReq As Google.Apis.Drive.v2.FilesResource.ListRequest
    Dim oFileList As FileList
    'mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'

    oListReq = oDriveService.Files.List()
    'Search for a specific file name
    oListReq.Q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and title = '" + ParentFolder + "' and trashed=false"
    oListReq.Fields = "items/id" 'MSO - 20130621 - only ID needed for next query
    oListReq.MaxResults = 10 'Max 10 files (too may I Expect only 1)

    'Get the results
    oFileList = oListReq.Fetch()

    'Only 1 result is expected
    If oFileList.Items.Count = 1 Then
        Dim oFile As File = oFileList.Items(0)
        FolderId = oFile.Id 'Get FolderId
    End If

    oListReq = oDriveService.Files.List()
    'Search for a specific file name in the folder
    oListReq.Q = "'" + FolderId + "' in parents and trashed=false "
    'oListReq.Fields = "items(id,alternateLink)" 'MSO - 20130621 - Optimize your query if you need only certain fields

    'Get the results
    oFileList = oListReq.Fetch()

    'TODO: oFileList now have the list of the files in the folder, but there could me more "pages"

End Sub
```

Not tested but it's **heavily** based on the code I run in a production environment, so it should work

Comment: Thanks! I only used the Q part from all that code, but it worked! :)

Comment: Why is the answer in what appears to be VB?

Comment: @Noob it's VB.net because it's almost a copy paste of the code I used in production at the time and function signatures are the same in VB.Net so I preferred to give a quick answer with some information instead of writing all the code back in C#

Answer (score 3):

You need to authenticate your requests with a valid access token. Go through OAuth 2.0 to learn how to retrieve an access token or use our Java client library that comes with OAuth 2.0 support [2].

[1] https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

[2] https://developers.google.com/drive/auth/web-server

Answer (score 2):

Using googleApis V3. This is sample code:

```
 string FolderId = "1lh-YnjfDFMuPVisoM-5p8rPeKkihtw9";
        // Define parameters of request.
        FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = DriveService.Files.List();
        listRequest.PageSize = 10;
        listRequest.Q = "'" + FolderId + "' in parents and trashed=false";
        listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(*)";

        // List files.
        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
            .Files;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This answer is the correct one and it works perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem in retrieving files and folder from a specific folder then follow this link it will help you in detail [Get all files and folder from specific folder in Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112178/how-can-we-list-all-files-from-a-specific-folder-on-google-drive/22834546#22834546)