# Cannot retrieved the files in a specific folder in google drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

In my case, all the files have been created via API can be retrieved, however the created file in a specific folder in google drive itself cannot be retrieved.

Example:

I have a folder named "Test".
   Now the user manually uploads or creates a file called "test.txt" in "Test" folder.
   The problem is I cannot retrieved the file created because it is created manually not using the API.

I have already use the **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive** which I have read in stackoverflow. But still cannot.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you checked file permission for which you have created manually ?

Comment: Yes.. Permission is ok.

Answer (score 0):

i have done it in python

`khol =  DRIVE.files().list(q="'%s' in parents"%<THE FOLDER ID>).execute().get('files', [])`

hope it helps

Comment: In php i've done

$parameters = array(
        'pageSize' => 100,
        'fields' => "nextPageToken, files(id,name)",
        'q' => "'".$folderId."' in parents"
        ); but still cannot retrived the files :(

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters), you can search for files with the [`files.list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) method of the Drive API. As referred with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112178/how-can-we-list-all-files-from-a-specific-folder-on-google-drive), you should use [`Files.list()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) with parameter `q='{{FOLDER_ID}}'` in `parents` and it will list all the files and its details of children of specific folder you want.

Comment: I have also the q= {folder_id} parameter but still can't retrieve the file :(